# Jenkins build failed after updating gradle

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I updated Gradle tools from 2.2.3 to 2.3.2. I don't have a problem to build a project on my local machine. However, Jenkins can't build the project. I've got following console output.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'workforce'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/repositories/zt-public-releases/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/repositories/zt-public-releases/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/repositories/zt-public-releases/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/repositories/zt-public-releases/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
     Required by:
         project : > com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/repositories/zt-public-releases/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://repos.zeroturnaround.com/nexus/content/repositories/zt-public-releases/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.jar
     Required by:
         project : > com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-plugin:0.8.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Do you have an idea, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As `https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom` that is mentioned in the error message **is** present and accessible, I guess your Jenkins does not have proper access to JCenter. Maybe some proxy that does not forward properly or something like that. Maybe it was a temporary hickup and if you try again it works. If not, maybe try to access this URL from your Jenkins worker via `curl` or `wget` to see whether the Jenkins host itself can access the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries update solved the problem.